# Unity: AddTorque() causes object to change its rotation axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm not sure how to exactly describe this issue. I'm rotating an object using AddTorque(), but the object immediately begins to change the axis around which it rotates (or it at least looks like so). Best check this gif to see what I mean: https://gfycat.com/hatefulbadandeancat

The code I have is this:

```
rigidbody.AddTorque(player.transform.up * -inputX * rotationForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Perhaps this is not an issue at all, but an expected behaviour. However, I would rather have this object rotate constantly just as it does at the very beginning and not change its rotation axis.

I tried using AddRelativeTorque() instead of AddTorque(), but then I couldn't get the object to rotate the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Is this rigidbody on the player that is referenced in the AddTorque function?

Comment: No, this is the rigidbody on that barrel shown in gif.

Comment: You need to rotate the object around its up axis. So, replace "player.transform.up" with "transform.up" or whatever represents the object's up axis

Comment: I tried different things. The point with "transform.up" is that this axis changes while object is rotating, so then the object rotates in different directions. I tried saving "transform.up" when player picks that object up and using that, but it also didn't work. I didn't have an issue like the one described above, but the barrel did not rotate the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to restrict rotation in the inspector and allow it to rotate on only one axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Vector3.up instead of transform.up if it helps your situation. But remember to align the object first

Comment: Hi. I tried using Vector3.up, but I did not align the object. How do I do that?

Comment: To reach the object rotation by angles, you can use eulerAngles. It translates the quaternion to angles by degrees.
This rotation is relative to the parent object, and if it has no parent, relative to world.